# My router is really slow. How can I troubleshoot?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have two routers at my home.

```
WAN -(LAN) - Media Link router - (LAN) - Buffalo router - (WiFi IEEE 802.11g) - PC1
                  |- (WiFi IEEE 802.11b/g/n) - PC2
```

When I compare the speed and stability, PC1 is much better than PC2. 
I believe my Media Link router has problem. How can I troubleshoot?

The results of [Wireless Diagnostics](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2476307/mac-os-x/os-x-mavericks--using-apple-s-hidden-wi-fi-diagnostics-tool.html) is:

```
media link  802.11n RSSI:-61    Noise:-92   Band:2.4GHz Width:40MHz
buffalo 802.11b/g   RSSI:-57    Noise:-89   Band:2.4GHz Width:20Mhz
```

Comment: According to the diagram, both are connecting via the Media link, so do you suspect the wifi part of the media link?

Comment: Yes, both are through Media link. Buffalo should be slower but actually connecting to Media link is slower. So I suspect that Media link's WiFi has problem.

Comment: Check the community wiki answer I put after [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/799089/network-disconnect-with-netgear-router)

Comment: Thanks for showing the relevant QA. That answer is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following things on PC2:

1. Strength of Wifi-Signal, whether the performance get better if the PC is about 3 Meters from the router. (I once have a Laptop that drops Wifi if placed beside the wifi router)
2. Whether PC2 is using the slow 802.11b.

Comment: Thanks. I have just tired Wireless Diagnostics on my MacBook. I added the result into the original post. Both of my routers are next each other and one of my laptop is there too. Probably I should drop WiFi of that laptop to avoid noise?

Comment: Try disable 40 MHz in media link router. Although 40 MHz meant to give you more throughput, there are more chances that incompatibility results in bad performances.

Comment: According to this article http://lifehacker.com/5931280/optimize-your-wi-fi-network-with-macs-hidden-diagnostic-tool you have a singal noise ratio of 30 dB which is quite good.

Comment: Thanks for showing great doc. Good to know 30dB is good enough. Let me keep watching. Sometimes the network becomes really slow. I will scan again at that time. Also let me try 20MHz instead of 20MHz/40MHz.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a router with 5G Hz and has three long antennas. 
Now I have the following:
    RSSI: -61 Noise: -92

Also I haven't seen any wireless issue for the past few weeks.

The point for my situation was:
 - Use 5GHz channel, which has more vacant channels. 
 - Use a router with good antennas.